# Extracting date from a string in JS

Tags: javascript, string

I have a string like so:

```
var string = "some text 2012-01-01 some more text here"
```

I would like to be able to extract the date from this string, or any one like it, and store the 2012-01-01 or whatever date is there to a variable.

I have found the `.match()` method but I am stuck from there.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var str =  "some text 2012-01-01 some more text here";
var rex = /\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/;
alert(str.match(rex));
```

Comment: Noting that `str.match()` will return either an array of one or more matches, or `null`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var string = "some text 2012-01-01 some more text here";

// you will be using regular expressions
string.match(/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/));
```

Comment: The poster is asking how to get the date out of the string, your answer does not answer that.

Comment: @epascarello—presumably that's your down vote. Strange, as this answer is almost exactly the same as the accepted answer.

Comment: @RobG,  person edited within the 3 minutes since that is not the original code which was just date code. :) Original code was just `new Date("2012-01-01")`

Answer (score 0):

Parsing strings is always a pain.  Even more so when parsing a date from within a string given the different formats that dates can have.  If the date will always be xxxx-xx-xx, then you could use a split() function splitting on a space " ", and then iterate across the array to find a string that could successfully parse to a date.

Based on my experience, however, if you can get it so your date comes to you in a better way, it will be many times easier for you.

Comment: The dates will always be in that format. So how would I go about getting the date out of the array?

Comment: oh.. others have suggested regex for matching the pattern.  if you can guarantee the format, then that's the best.  :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var str="some text 2012-01-01 some more text here";
var pattern=/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]/gi;
alert(str.match(pattern));
```

And a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/emvEf/) if you would like.